# Tweepy Django redirect

Tags: python, django, tweepy

I am working on a project with tweepy and django for some reason I cannot get the site to stop going to example.com with the response. I have tried deleteting example.com from the admin site and adding my host, as well as changing the default domain and the allowed hosts to my site. This is running on an ec2 instance.
After I login in  I get redirected to a 'http://example.com/auth/twitter/callback/?oauth_token=sdfsdfsdfsdfsd&oauth_verifier=sdfsdfwekjfdsljf' (note values returned from callback are made up for security)

UPDATE - I have deployed to apache2 and still get the same error

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for starterSite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.9.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '####'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True




# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'twitSent',
    'django.contrib.sites',

]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'twitSent.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'starterSite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
   'http://example.com:8888', # allows viewing of instances directly
]
DEFAULT_DOMAIN = 'http://example.com:8888'


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/twitstat/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

views.py

```
#from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.
import tweepy
from django.http import *
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import logout



CONSUMER_KEY = '####'
CONSUMER_SECRET = '###'

def get_api(request):
    # set up and return a twitter api object
    oauth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    access_key = request.session['access_key_tw']
    access_secret = request.session['access_secret_tw']
    oauth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(oauth)
    return api

def main(request):
    """
    main view of app, either login page or info page
    """
    # if we haven't authorised yet, direct to login page
    if check_key(request):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('info'))
    else:
        return render_to_response('twitSent/login.html')

def unauth(request):
    """
    logout and remove all session data
    """
    if check_key(request):
        api = get_api(request)
        request.session.clear()
        logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main'))

def info(request):
    """
    display some user info to show we have authenticated successfully
    """
    if check_key(request):
        api = get_api(request)
        user = api.me()
        return render_to_response('twitSent/info.html', {'user' : user})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main'))

def auth(request):
    # start the OAuth process, set up a handler with our details
    oauth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    # direct the user to the authentication url
    # if user is logged-in and authorized then transparently goto the callback URL
    auth_url = oauth.get_authorization_url(True)
    response = HttpResponseRedirect(auth_url)
    # store the request token
    request.session['unauthed_token_tw'] = (oauth.request_token['oauth_token'], oauth.request_token['oauth_token_secret']) 
    return response

def callback(request):
    verifier = request.GET.get('oauth_verifier')
    oauth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    token = request.session.get('unauthed_token_tw', None)
    # remove the request token now we don't need it
    request.session.delete('unauthed_token_tw')
    oauth.set_request_token(token[0], token[1])
    # get the access token and store
    try:
        oauth.get_access_token(verifier)
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        print('Error, failed to get access token')
    request.session['access_key_tw'] = oauth.access_token.key
    request.session['access_secret_tw'] = oauth.access_token.secret
    response = HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('info'))
    return response

def check_key(request):
    """
    Check to see if we already have an access_key stored, if we do then we have already gone through 
    OAuth. If not then we haven't and we probably need to.
    """
    try:
        access_key = request.session.get('access_key_tw', None)
        if not access_key:
            return False
    except KeyError:
        return False
    return True
```

urls.py (in app folder)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [ #'twitter_auth.views',
    url(r'^$', views.main, name='main'),
    url(r'^callback/$', views.callback, name='auth_return'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.unauth, name='oauth_unauth'),
    url(r'^auth/$', views.auth, name='oauth_auth'),
    url(r'^info/$', views.info, name='info'),
]
```

login.html

```
{% extends "twitSent/base.html" %}

    {% block content %}
    <div id="container">
        <h2>Welcome!</h2>
        <p>Sign in with Twitter to begin.</p>
        <p><a href="{% url 'oauth_auth' %}"><img src="https://si0.twimg.com/images/dev/buttons/sign-in-with-twitter-d.png" alt="sign in with twitter" /></a></p>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

info.html

```
{% extends "twitSent/base.html" %}

    {% block content %}
        <div id="container">
            <img src="{{user.profile_image_url}}" />
            <h3>{{user.name}}</h3>
            <p>{{user.screen_name}}<p/>
            <a href="/logout/" title="logout">logout</a>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: What url did you pass as your callback url in the Twitter app settings?

Comment: I am putting this as answer. Please accept it.

Comment: do you have any idea what I should use as my callback url?

Comment: currently its just my hostname

Comment: The full url to your callback view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we send the user to Twitter for authentication, Twitter redirects the user to the url we set as call back url in the app settings.

You can however, override this callback url when sending the user to twitter for authorization.